# How to build and sign an apk file?

Tags: php, android, bash, shell, sdk

I want create an APK file and sign it using PHP. I read many posts here for this and all of them suggested to install SDK on server and use `exec` or `shell_exec` to build the project.

Well, that's pretty easy but how can I sign it using PHP? I use the `keytool` `command for signing APK, but while signing it asks me for many details like my key passphrase, my name, and my organization details. I don't know how to give this information when using PHP.

For an instance:

```
###SHELL###
$  keytool -genkey -v -keystore TestApp.keystore -alias TestApp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
    Enter passphrase: my  passphrase here
    Repeat the passphrase: my passphrase again
    Enter your full name: my name
    Enter your organization unit: my org. unit
    Enter your organization name: my org. name
    Enter password for keystore (press return for same as key passphrase): i press enter here

   Success!!

$ _
```

How can I provide those details using PHP's `shell_exec` function?

Comment: If I recall, most of the inputs to jarsigner can be provided as command line arguments.  The exception is the keystore password, which they don't want you putting there as command lines are often easily snooped.  I think I recall being able to pipe it into the stdin of the jarsigner process.  Automated built scripts (as used on build servers) of course solve this, so you might look at some of those.

Comment: @ChrisStratton can you please give an example on how to pipe it into stdin? :) seems confusing to me

Comment: That seems the kind of thing you should be asking a search engine.